# How does the else statement in python execute when we have two parameters?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
def test(i,j):
if(i==0):
    return j
else:
    return test(i-1,i+j)
```

print(test(4,7))

I understand that i=4 and 4 is not equal to zero, therefore the second condition is executed but how does "test(i-1,i+j) work? Do you substitute i and j? eg. (3-1,3+7)? Can someone please clarify this for me as I am highly confused.

Comment: yes `test(i-1, i+j)` would become `test(3, 11)`. You can add a print statement before the if condition to print the values of i and j and then run your function to see the flow.

Comment: Does the whole function get executed again with those new values until the condition (i==0) returns true?

Comment: @user14255281 Yes, exactly.

Comment: You might want to try to run your code in https://pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 1):

this is called a recursive function, you might notice that the function calls itself. Usually those functions have base conditions, which will stop the recursion, in your case, it's when i reaches zero.
But be careful: if you start with a negative value for i, you won't reach the base condition, since i is getting decreased by one in each call:
e.g.: let's say i=-1 and j=10 => test(-1,10)

test(-1,10): i is not equal to zero, therefore else block is applied:
test(i-1, i+j) -> test(-1-1, -1+10) -> test(-2, -9)

test(-2, -9): i is not equal to zero, therefore else block is applied:

test(i-1, i+j) -> test(-2-1, -2+9) -> test(-3, -7)

test(-3, -7)

... as you can see, i get's decremented in each call and ONLY stops when i is equal to zero.

This also explained the logic of the recursive function:

```
test(4,7) -> return test(3,11) 
          -> return test(2,14)
          -> return test(1,16)
          -> return test(0, 17)
          -> return 17 (base condition is reached, i==0)
```

Now, the recursion goes backwards and the 17 is returned to the first call.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @AdroMine, you can modify your function to print the values of `i` and `j` before each recursive call to `test()`:

```
def test(i, j):
    print(f'i = {i} j = {j}')
    if (i == 0):
        return j
    else:
        return test(i-1, i+j)
```

Calling `test(4, 7)` would result in:

```txt
i = 4 j = 7
i = 3 j = 11
i = 2 j = 14
i = 1 j = 16
i = 0 j = 17
```

This function calculates the sum of `j` and `i`, `i-1`, `i-2`, ..., `1`.

> how does "test(i-1,i+j) work?

At every call:

- The value of `i` is decremented by `1`, then passed as a first argument.
- The value of `j + i` is calculated, then passed as a second argument (returned when `i` is equal to `0`).

In other words:

- The first parameter `i` serves the purpose of the loop counter.
- The second parameter `j` serves the purpose of holding the sum.

To better clear things, you can write an iterative version of `test()`:

```
def test2(a, b):
    j = b
    for i in range (a, 0, -1):
        j += i
    
    return j
```